# How do I create a runtime TCalendarEdit?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I want to create a TCalendarEdit in runtime and I have been able to create a TEdit and a TClearingEdit, but when I try the same method for the TCalendarEdit it doesn't work. When I run it I get a pop-up message saying "Cannot create a circular dependency beetwen components". I know beetwen is spelled incorrect but that's really what the message says!

Here is my code that I tried to implement a TCalenderEdit in runtime:

```
editCalendar := TCalendarEdit(Self);
editCalendar.Parent := fAfspraakItem;
editCalendar.Align := TAlignLayout.alRight;
editCalendar.Width := 150;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not trying to create a `TCalendarEdit`, you're trying to typecast `Self` as a `TCalendarEdit` and assign it to `editCalendar`.

Change your code to

```
editCalendar := TCalendarEdit.Create(Self);
```